# Auto login using Aws cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

I am using aws Cognito for user authentication in my android application, I want that once the user log ins into the app, he should be able to auto login into the app. unless he logs out of the app. Can anyone give me any pointers on how i can implement it?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment [cognito android library](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android) manages it for you.  Library would refresh *idToken* and *accessToken*, you just need to retrieve them each time from the library and try not to store/cache for a long anywhere (both are valid for 1 hour). getAuthenticationDetails() method (used to get your credentials) wouldn't be triggered, until refresh token is valid.

The library is using *refresh token* to refresh idToken and accessToken. Refresh token is valid (by default) for [30 days from last login](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-refresh-token). You could extend the value to 3650 days (max), but currently android library doesn't support this feature.